# Adding Condition in Styling using its own or parent's css property as condition in REACT

Tags: css, reactjs, styling

Recently, I was working in a React project, And it got me thinking if i can use **react style propery as condition.** 
Here's my working code \

```
const {_,width} = useDimensionHook()
<Component
     styles={{
       position: width < 991 ? "absolute" : "fixed",
       top: width < 991 ? 0 : 42
     }}
/>
```

What I want to know if I can do something like,

```
const {_,width} = useDimensionHook()
<Component
     styles={{
       position: width < 991 ? "absolute" : "fixed",
       top: position == 'absolute' ? 0 : 42 
          // using css property **position** inside same styling
     }}
/>
```

I need your suggestions. Maybe applying parent first and then use that styling in its children. But I don't know the exact answer. Need your help 
*Thanks*

Comment: its more like a good code practice question rather than just showing outputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can definitely do that by simple storing the computed value of `position` in a variable, and then using it in a ternary statement. On top of that, you can take advantage of [`useMemo`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo) to return a memoized value:

```
const {_,width} = useDimensionHook();
const myCustomStyles = useMemo(() => {
     const position = width < 991 ? 'absolute' : 'fixed';

     return {
          position,
          top: position === 'absolute' ? 0 : 42,
     }
}, [width]);

<Component styles={myCustomStyles} />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set styles in a constant and then use that to check it's value for your condition

like this :

```
  const {_,width} = useDimensionHook()
  const componentStyles = {
    position: width < 991 ? 'absolute' : 'fixed',
  };

  return (
    <Component
      styles={{
        ...componentStyles,
        top: componentStyles.position == 'absolute' ? 0 : 42,
      }}
    />
  );
```